# Benchmark for iOS development frameworks

Tags: ios, performance, cocoa, jquery-mobile, sencha-touch

Is there a benchmark with Cocoa, JQuery Mobile, Sencha Touch, titanium, etc?
Can we see a real difference between them?

Do you think speed is a limit for a framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting aside browser-based frameworks, which are at a distinct disadvantage in terms of performance, iOS native-code frameworks are likely to perform quite similarly to the same application written in CocoaTouch (of course it might vary, particularly if the framework provides some useful-but-slow functionality that you use).

I'm a big fan of MonoTouch and feel strongly that it allows me to program in a modern programming language, across platforms, without paying any significant penalty in terms of performance or capability.